# Generate voluntary error for Materialized View update test

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Good night friends,

I am creating a script to send mail when the update of the materialized view does not update correctly.

How can I make a simple test script, create a script that generates an error in an intensional way to validate that the sending of mail is working when the specific update error is triggered.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_mv
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND

AS
    SELECT * FROM XXXXX;
```

generate error when executing the update.

exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('emp_mv');

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this gives you some control

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW emp_mv
REFRESH COMPLETE
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT x.*, 1 / ( select count(*) from t ) flag
FROM XXXXX x;
```

and your table T has either no rows (results in error) or >0 rows (works fine).

Comment: It helped me a lot, but I did not get the error.((PL / SQL procedure completed successfully)) What I did was delete the table T once the materialized view was created, then the error was thrown there. Thank you so much.